# Convert from Float to integer

Tags: java, android, floating-point, int

I built a simple Android "accelerometer" Sensor Application.

This is The [Java Code link](http://pastebin.com/zDsDtpnJ).

The output is like this:

X:8.87654322
Y:0.564321 
Z:4.0195783

And sometimes it goes longer ...

I want to convert the float to an integer or just have 2 numbers

(I'm a beginner In Java.)
Thanks

Comment: What result are you aiming for?

Comment: `I want to convert to integer or just have 2 numbers` do you mean 2 decimal points? If so, which do you want, the integer or 2 decimals?

Comment: `int x = (int) 8.8f;`

Comment: Cruncher , It Will be better If i only have integer number

Comment: i want To know how to convert the float to integer with my java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double y = 9.37923929732232;
int a = (int)y;
```

Comment: I have a hunch that he'd rather round the int instead of truncating it

Answer (score 0):

```
double d = 4.232
int answer = (int) Math.round(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to convert float array values of accelerometer to int below is the float array with two float values i am just rounding off the value of float element of oth index using Math.round(arrayname[indexnumber])

```
float[] fArray = new float[] {(float) 6574.748, (float) 789.999};

    int f1 = Math.round(fArray[0]);
    System.out.println(f1);
```

this will round off the float value for ex 6574.748 will be rounded to 6575

Answer (score 0):

To convert float sensor data to integer you have to mutiply them, and then round.

e.g you want 1 digit after comma. 0.56432 -> 6

```
double y = 0.564321;
int yi = (int) Math.Round(y * 10); // for taking 2 digits after comma use 100
```

Then you have handy acceleration sensor data.

Comment: I just want an integer number , but i don't know how to use it with my java code , thanks

Answer (score -1):

For getting two decimal places use ([java.text.DecimalFormat:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html))

You can try this

```
 double roundTwoDecimals(double d) { 
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
 }
```

For integer there are other answers in the post.